Subset selection of (multidimensional) array without loosing dimensions
I have a large array envSST with dimension (720,361,10,276)
I am actually only interested in a small subset of the first two dimensions, given by a 54x2 matrix called lat.lon.ensinds, so I can delete envSST and free up some space.
Two things I have tried:
eSST <- t(sapply(1:nrow(lat.lon.ensinds), function (k)
  ensSST[lat.lon.ensinds$lon.inds[k], lat.lon.ensinds$lat.inds[k], , ]))

which results in a matrix of dimension (54,2760) instead of an array of size (54,10,276)
(I tried adding the sapply argument simplify="array" but it resulted in an error)
eSST <- NULL
eSST <- rbind(eSST, ensSST[lat.lon.ensinds$lon.inds[k],
                           lat.lon.ensinds$lat.inds[k], , ])

which results in a matrix of size (540,276) instead of an array
Any suggestions?

This is easy to fix if you understand that the result of `[`() is coerced to the lowest possible dimension if you don't use drop=FALSE.
Consider this example array:
> (A <- array(,c(2, 2, 2, 2)))
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA

Where
> dim(A)
[1] 2 2 2 2

Coerced,
> A[1:2, 1, , ]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA

not coerced.
> A[1:2, 1, , , drop=FALSE]
, , 1, 1

     [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA

, , 2, 1

     [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA

, , 1, 2

     [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA

, , 2, 2

     [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA


The solution was easy:
eSST=array(NA,dim=c(54,54,10,276))

for (k in 1:54) eSST[k,k,,]=ensSST[lat.lon.ensinds$lon.inds[k], lat.lon.ensinds$lat.inds[k],,]

